# how to run two process at a time in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

```
 Imports System.Threading.Thread
 Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    While i <= 10
        TextBox1.Text = i.ToString()
        TextBox1.Refresh()
        Sleep(1000)
        i = i + 1
    End While
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim lbl As Label
    Dim matches() As Control
    matches = Me.Controls.Find("Label" & TextBox1.Text, True)
    If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is Label Then
        lbl = DirectCast(matches(0), Label)
        lbl.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

If i click button1 then it is showing 1 to 10 in textbox each after one second. It is working fine. after clicked button1 when textbox.text=2 that time i want to press button2. if i press button2 then it should show the label2.backcolor=yellow. label no is textbox.text. Problem is : After finished while loop in button1 then only i can press button2. we are getting only label10 as yellow color after finished while loop. Solution : I want to click that button2 before ending while loop. Please give solution. Actually i want which number is showing in textbox1.text that label should be yellow color.

Comment: You need to spin up a new thread for the Button1.Click handler.  You can read how to do that by searching Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning: terrible code follows (but it works!)

```
Private Sub Wait(ByVal time As Integer) 'in milliseconds
    Dim secs As Integer = Environment.TickCount
    While Environment.TickCount < secs + time
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While

End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    While i <= 10
        Label1.Text = i.ToString()
        Label1.Refresh()
        Wait(1000)
        i = i + 1
    End While
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Static toggle As Boolean
    If toggle Then
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Green
    Else
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Blue
    End If
    toggle = Not toggle
End Sub
```

Comment: It may work, but if you have to call `.DoEvents()` it's probably wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your `While` loop in `Button1.Click` is blocking the UI thread, and therefore blocking the `Button2.Click` handler until `Button1.Click` finishes.  One simple solution would be to make `Button1.Click` `Async` (assuming .NET 4.5+) and use `Task.Delay(1000)` instead:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    While i <= 10
        TextBox1.Text = i.ToString()
        TextBox1.Refresh()
        'Sleep(1000)
        Await Task.Delay(1000)
        i = i + 1
    End While
End Sub
```

This will free up the UI thread when the `Await` is hit.

You could also use a background thread, but then you would have to ensure that your UI updates happen on the UI thread.

Comment: if i use this code   Await Task.Delay(1000) it is working in another program.in my current program it is showing error like this. (1.system action not defined.2.you cant find all required by asyns modifier. are you trying wrong framwork version.

Comment: What is the solution can u please help me?

Comment: @BuvaneswariSekar What is the target .NET framework version for your current application?  It is shown on the project properties page, in the Application tab.  And what version of Visual Studio are you working.  Async support was added in .NET 4.5 / Visual Studio 2012, but it is possible to get working with .NET 4.0 / VS2012+ with some additional dependencies (BCL libs from NuGet).  I would guess you have VS2012+ if another application is working, but maybe targetted an earlier framework for the app that isn't working.

Comment: yea am using vs2012 .Net 4.5. i did that another application (vs2012 .Net 4.5) but its working.. current program also am doing in the same version. but it is showing above error.What is the solution? is there any other way to do?

Comment: am using .Net 4.5 Error:An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: Actually my current application was working in .Net 2.0. to use this code( Await Task.Delay(1000). i changed version as .Net 4.5. after changed version showing  Error:An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. What i have to do?

Comment: current application am doing in vs2012 .Net 2.0